# Making a webapp with listboxes based on Google Spreadsheets with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, listboxitem

Note: This question has been rewritten completely due to changes in my original code.

Hi, I have my Code.gs file and my index.html file. I am trying to create listbox in my index.html file with data from Code.gs.

I did some testing, and the following code gives the results I want:

```
<select multiple>
<option> <?= articleNumbers(0)[[0]]?> </option>
<option> <?= articleNumbers(0)[[1]]?> </option>
<option> <?= articleNumbers(0)[[2]]?> </option>
<option> <?= articleNumbers(1)[[0]]?> </option>
<option> <?= articleNumbers(1)[[2]]?> </option>
</select>
```

However, I am making 12 - and counting - listboxes with up to hundreds of values to be inserted from a spreadsheet, so I need to make them with a loop. I tried the following code, hoping the option-tag would go in a loop, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<select multiple> 
<? for (i=0; i < 11; i++){ 
        for (j=0; j < articleNumbers(i).length; j++){  ?>  
            <option><?=articleNumbers(i)[[j]]?> </option>
       <?} 
} ?>
</select>
```

Any suggestions

Comment: Its somewhat long. First make a minimal example that shows the problem. Also use step debug to see if the code goes where you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll try them out.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just realized i forgot the `var i` and `var j`. The correct code is as follows

```
<select multiple> 
<? for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++){ 
      for (var j = 0; j < articleNumbers(i).length; j++){  ?>  
        <option><?=articleNumbers(i)[[j]]?> </option>
   <?} 
} ?>
</select>
```